# Add heading to Google Docs document from iPhone

Tags: iphone, google-docs

quite a straightforward question. I started to really like Google Docs and the fact I can edit them from iPhone from the mobile site.

However, I would like to add headings to the documents while editing on iPhone. It is not possible through any drop-menu, but isn't there some sort of hack?

Comment: I know you've already been kicked from SuperUser, but you might also get a chance if you ask this question on WebApps. Since it's got more to do with Google Docs that the iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest several for title editing, but I'm unaware of any that offer headings.

If you've already scanned through the available App Store offerings without much success, then I can suggest little-else. It's not about a hack, as Google hasn't gone out of their way to restrict you in this fashion. Probably on the long list of to-do's.